# Add a 'placeholder' row in a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-web-developer

I want to allow users to go through a set of tables, first creating a row in one table, then creating a row that is inserted with the previous row as a key.

Because the subsequent GridViews have no data until their previous rows are entered, the HTML for the table isn't rendered.

I want to add a placeholder row to ensure that the GridViews are always present with just an example row saying something like 'No data added yet'.

Is this possible? Perhaps a dummy row added programatically rather than being a feature of the control?

Thanks.

Comment: is the "dummy row" the only row ?

Comment: How do you mean? It would be the only row until databind provides at least one row from the database. I have had a go with the emptydatatemplate but it looks poor, I want it to be identical to how the table would normally be formatted and just have a row auto merged across all field saying there is no data yet.

Comment: I wanted in one of my projects to have a gridview that shows both header and footer even when empty so I did something as described here: http://weblogs.asp.net/joewrobel/archive/2008/01/30/a-more-elegant-solution-to-display-gridview-header-and-footer-when-the-data-source-is-empty.aspx , maybe this can help you- it gives you more control over what is displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [EmptyDataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.emptydatatemplate.aspx) property of the GridView:

```
<asp:gridview id="CustomersGridView" 
    datasourceid="CustomersSqlDataSource" 
    autogeneratecolumns="true"
    runat="server">
    <emptydatarowstyle backcolor="LightBlue"
      forecolor="Red"/>
    <emptydatatemplate>
      <asp:image id="NoDataImage"
        imageurl="~/images/Image.jpg"
        alternatetext="No Image" 
        runat="server"/>
        No Data Found.  
    </emptydatatemplate> 
  </asp:gridview>
```

Comment: I have had a go with the emptydatatemplate but it looks poor, I want it to be identical to how the table would normally be formatted and just have a row auto merged across all field saying there is no data yet.

Comment: You can format the emptydataitem exactly as it would look if there was one of your rows, simply put a '<table>' with one row inside.

Answer (score 0):

A dummy row worked for me in a similar case.

```
            DataRow dr = mDataTable.NewRow();
            dr["KEY"] = "DUMMY";
            mDataTable.Rows.Add(dr);

            DataView pView = new DataView(mDataTable);
            gridView.DataSource = pView;
            gridView.DataBind();

            gridView.Rows[0].CssClass = "Hidden"; //I am not sure about this actually, see the result
```

You can try this as an alternative, if other solutions donT work.